# Limit of $ \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-x)^n}{1+n!} $ as $x\rightarrow +\infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, power-series

The series of functions
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-x)^n}{1+n!}
$$
is pointwise convergent for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$, thus it defines the function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-x)^n}{1+n!}$. Is there a way to evaluate the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} f(x)$?

Comment: Do you mean, $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-x)^n}{1+n!}$?

Answer (score 0):

Write
$$
f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{1+n!}
$$
of course an entire function.  We want to know about $\lim_{z \to -\infty} f(z)$.  Maple produced this graph numerically.
[image: f(z)]

So I guess that $\lim_{z \to -\infty} f(z) = +\infty$.